# Date displaying a day off using date filter in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have following date being returned by the data

```
"2008-02-25T00:00:00Z"
```

When I display it using

```
 <span>{{meetingDate | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</span>
```

I get date display

```
 "02/24/2008"
```

Basically it is showing 24 instead of 25 loosing a day. 
Can you tell me how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out

**[Working Code](http://jsfiddle.net/CkBWL/146/)**

**script**

```
  var localDate = new Date('2008-02-25T00:00:00Z');
  var localTime = localDate.getTime();
  var localOffset = localDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
  $scope.mydate = new Date(localTime + localOffset);
```

**html**

```
{{mydate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}
```

**Output**

```
02/25/2008
```

Comment: Its working but can you explain what that code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a timezone issue. Your client machine must be on a timezone **less than 0 (UTC time)**. In general, this is not a problem as it's displaying the correct time based on client machine.